# Dividing the area of a circle with a chord that is tangent to a sufficiently smaller circle inside

Tags: geometry, circles

Consider a circle *C*, with center *O* and a smaller circle *c*, with center *o* such that *c* is completely inside *C* but does not contain *O*. Any tangent of *c* divides *C* into two parts *A* and *B*, where *A*>*B*. How may I identify the tangent of *c* that maximizes *A* and minimizes *B* given that *o* cannot be inside A?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chord you want in the one that's furthest from the center of the large circle.

If the large circle completely contains small circle $c$ it's the far from $O$ tangent to $c$ perpendicular to the line joining the centers of the two circles.

If the small circle is not completely contained in the large one then the furthest point from the center will not be inside the large circle. Then the question becomes really interesting.

In this picture I've drawn the small circle $c$ and the center $O$ of the large circle (but not the large circle, yet).

Watch what happens to the dotted line distance from $O$ to the tangent to $c$ as you move the point of tangency around $c$. As you move from $A$ to $B$ to $C$ the distance decreases from $|OA|$ to $0$.
As you move from $C$ to $D$ the distance increases from $0$ to $|OA|$.
So in the range from $A$ to $D$ furthest tangent is the one at $A$.
As you move from $D$ through $E$ to $F$ the distance increases again, to its maximum $|OF|$.

Therefore the choice of tangent point for the furthest tangent line is $A$ as long as the big circle cuts the small circle $c$ between $A$ and $D$. After that, use the tangent at the point where the two circles cross. If they don't cross (the small one is inside the large one) use $F$, of course.

[image]

Comment: I don't have the reputation points to upvote this yet but I will make sure to do that when I do. I have a follow-up question (only if you want to answer). I made a slight blunder in the question. What if there was an additional restriction that the center of the small circle cannot be included in A? Must I include this as another question or is the comment box sufficient?

Comment: Edit the question (not usually the right thing to do but OK here since no one else has answered) and see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks and will do!